# Does no.of columns effect read query performance with projection

Tags: sql

Consider that I have a table USERS_1 with 2 columns : `id` and `name`
and another table USERS_2 with 3 columns: `id`, `name` and `age`.
I have indexes on `id` on both tables and both tables contains 20 rows with same date for id and name. Lets consider postgres DB as an example.

Will there be a performance difference between the following queries:

1. SELECT id, name FROM USERS_1 WHERE id < 10
2. SELECT id, name FROM USERS_2 WHERE id < 10

Lets say this WHERE clause matches with 5 rows in both tables.

I have heard that since the no.of columns are more in USERS_2, the I/O operations to be done might be more as the DB server has to read the entire row from disk, before projecting. Projection only helps in transferring lesser data to the client. Is that correct?
Ref: [https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3764712/does-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table-can-affect-the-performance#:~:text=So%20yes%2C%20250%20columns%20typically,rows%20of%205%20cols%20each](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/3764712/does-the-number-of-columns-in-a-table-can-affect-the-performance#:%7E:text=So%20yes%2C%20250%20columns%20typically,rows%20of%205%20cols%20each).

I do know that the no.of rows and columns are too minimal to observe any performance difference, but the intent is to understand how projection and I/O reads are related.

Comment: A couple of questions:

Comment: 1.  Do you have a specific, measurable performance problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: 2.  Have you run some benchmark tests?  What were the results?

Comment: No need to worry if you don't have any performance problems.

Comment: Well. This is not for practical reasons, merely for understanding DB internals. I've not run any benchmarks and not practical use case to solve.

Comment: Was reading about DB internals and this doubt came across my mind. Hence, put it forward in very simple terms

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.